# How to do something on a delay after a button press in Swift but, postpone the delay each time the button is pressed?

Tags: swift, macos, timer, dispatch-queue

I'm working on a Swift app that is listening for a button press, and n seconds after the button is last pressed I want to display an alert. But if a user spams the button before n seconds is up, I want to reset the delay back to n seconds on each button press without just displaying multiple alerts.

There are obviously ways to do something after a delay in Swift (using `DispatchQueue` or `Timer`, etc.), but I'm struggling to figure out how to 'extend' the delay if the button is pressed again before the delay of n seconds completes.

Has anyone dealt with this issue or have any suggestions for how to tackle this type of problem?

Comment: Cancel the timer and start a new one?

Comment: Make your Timer property a weak variable. When the user presses the button, use "?" to invalidate the timer, then start at new one. If it has already been invalidated, it will be nil so the `timer?.invalidate()` call won't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a Timer for the delay, you can invalidate it each time, effectively resetting it. (I think you'll have to use a ViewModel for this, because you can't have a timer variable attached to a view.) Something like this:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var displayText = false
    
    var timer: Timer? = nil
    
    func setupTimer() {

        // "reset" the timer
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        // delays for 3 seconds
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { timer in
            self.displayText = true
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if viewModel.displayText {
                Text("Delayed Display")
            }
            
            Text("Button to Start Delayed Display")
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewModel.setupTimer()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP did not mention SwiftUI

Comment: Ah, that's true, but that's the only version of Swift I know. =) I think this solution is easily portable to UIKit if they're still using that!